# DI: When to list dependencies as params in ctor and when to call Container.Resolve<>()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I use DI quite a lot in my projects and I'm fairly comfortable with the concept, however there's one aspect which I'm not quite sure about.

So a common use-case for me is to have an ASP.NET MVC Controller where I list the controller's dependencies in the constructor's parameter list, obviously these are passed in when the Controller is constructed by the DI Container, I then assign these to readonly private variables to be later consumed by Actions within the Controller.

Now, my concern is that if I only use an injected dependency (let's say an `IMemberRepository`) within one Action (and let's say there are 5 other Actions), **should I list this as a dependency in the ctor, or should I call `Container.Resolve<IMemberRepository>()` within the one Action where it's used?**

I have to say, I do like listing all my dependencies in the ctor, and I don't particularly like `Container.Resolve<>()` strewn throughout my code, but, going on the example above, there's no point in getting the DI container to instantiate an `IMemberRepository` if it's going to be used!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never call Container.Resolve from within your application code. This is the Service Locator pattern, and is [considered an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx). Not injecting all dependencies through the constructor means you are hiding the used dependencies, which makes it less clear what depenencies a class has and makes it harder to test that class.

You are concerned about performance when dependencies are injected but not used, but this is normally not an issue, since construction of objects is usually very fast (since all those objects should do during construction is storing all incoming dependencies in private fields). When construction is proven to be too slow for a certaintype, there are other solutions, such as wrapping that dependency into a proxy that lazily initializes that dependency.

If you find that your class gets too many constructor arguments, it is a sign that it has [too many responsibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle); it is doing too much. Try to repair this flaw in the class's design instead of falling back to `Container.Resolve`. For instance, extract a group of dependencies with the classes logic into a single new type and inject that as dependency.

There could be other problems with the design. When your controller depends directly on a repository dependency and you have business logic in the controller, you are missing an abstraction. You are missing a service layer. A good solution is the introduction of [command handlers](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [query handlers](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

Answer (score 1):

I second what Steven has said.

If too many constructor arguments bug you then you could also opt for property injection.  I favour this approach.  There are some objects that, for some or other reason, are not injected into properties if they are not yet fully populated whereas they will be injected into the constructor.

I apply a guard to the dependency on properties to throw an exception if a dependency is null so that I know which dependency it is.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that it depends on what you are wanting to do with DI.

The approach of using the injected dependencies as parameter in the constructor can end in a very long list of parameters.
This may be necessary for real Test Driven Development where you may want to mock the methods for your injected dependencies.

I personally think that it produces a lot of overhead as the DI Container always has to construct all dependencies, needed in an Action or not.
It is also to be considered that the usage of `Actions` and `PartialViews` produce a lot more constructions.

E.g.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMemberRepository _memberRepo = null;

    public HomeController(IMemberRepository repo)
    {
        _memberRepo = repo;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyViewModel viewModel = _memberRepo.DoSomething();
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult SomePartialAction()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

Where the view `Index.cshtml` calls the partial view `SomePartialAction()` by `@Html.Action("SomePartialAction")`.
In this case the constructor of the controller is called twice. Each time for each action. Therefore the DI container is also called twice.

So it really depends. For "hardcore" TDD you have to use the constructor. Otherwise I would resolve the dependencies where and when needed.

Comment: I totally disagree with you. Injecting dependencies that are just sometimes used does normally give no noticable overhead, and if it does, there are other ways around this. You should never revert to using the Service Locator anti-pattern.

Comment: I agree that the service locator pattern should not be used, but in the case of a lot dependencies and only some being used by some actions is a code smell that says "Break the class/controller up into smaller ones" so that the relative dependencies are used with the correct class/controller

Comment: I agree with the service locator pattern. I just didn't knew that. But regarding the complexity a web app may have, it is not just that easy to break a controller into smaller ones.

Comment: Sure it is, I do it all the time, all a controller is is a way of routing. So if you had an action in Home/SomeAction and that rendered the View SomeAction. If SomeAction was really related to say NewFunctionalityController, you just move the action to the new controller. Now to access the SomeAction view you just call /NewFunctionality/SomeAction. Anywhere that originally referenced Home/SomeAction  can easily be updated. A controller is nothing more than a container to hold actions that render views/receive posts/return json, etc... the app doesn't care where the actions live

Comment: That is true, but you also want to keep partial actions in the correct controller. Say you have a View containing 18 partial actions (not just simple views) that all show various information about the same item. When I want to change one of those items I want to know where to find it.